# Restoring my current Time Machine (Lion) with my DVD of Leopard?

Tags: time-machine

I have bought a new HD and I want to remplace the one I have in my MBP. In wonder if I will be able to restore my current backup made by Time Machine, since I've upgraded my OS to Lion (Using Apple Store). So the only DVD I have is the one I got with my laptop. I think it's Leopard.

Are those 2 versions of Time Machine compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a USB to SATA adapter or drive caddy, you can easily put your new HDD into this, use Disk Utility to partition it with a GUID partition table and format it Mac OS Extended Journaled.

Once that's done, restart your system and hold CMD + R to boot into the Lion recovery mode. From there you can choose to install Lion to your new drive. Once that's done you can migrate from the internal drive so that the new drive is now running Lion and has all of your data.

Now you can safely swap the drives over.

If you have no USB to SATA adapter, or drive caddy, you can create a USB Lion installer with Apple's own [Lion Recovery Disk Assistant](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1433) to install Lion on the new drive, and then restore your data from Time Machine.

You shouldn't need to touch the Leopard DVD this way.

Comment: FYI : I made a "USB key Lion Recovery", and that was it. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/54980/115) answer on AskDifferent will give you an idea of what you need.

You can restore a Snow Leopard Time Machine into Lion (using migration assistant for example), but I'm almost sure I read somewhere that Leopard (10.5) -> Lion was not supported due to changes in the structure.