# Install a new SSD but keep all the files and everything

Tags: ssd, carbon-copy-cloner

I bought a new SSD for my Macbook Pro Retina 2014. I want to be able to insert the new SSD but keep all my files, setting and etc. I am not sure what to do how can I clone my existing SSD to the new SSD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a complete duplicate ("clone") of your existing internal SSD module onto the new SSD.
You can do this with Disk Utility, but the third-party apps  [SuperDuper!](https://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html) and [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com) are actually better at it.

However, the real problem is having both SSDs attached at the same time to make the transfer. You either need to buy a USB enclosure for one of them, or you need to have an additional USB drive to copy the clone to as an intermediary. You also need to have MacOS on this USB drive, because you'll need to boot up to it.

(Having a standard USB drive may be more use to you in the long-run,; or you may already have one.)

First step is to copy the clone onto the USB drive. You can either make the entire disk a clone, or copy the clone as a disk image (file) onto the USB.

Next, you need to install the new SSD in your Mac so you can copy the clone back onto it, but of course you need to be booted to another volume in order to run the cloning app!

Boot to the USB drive, and then run the cloning software in the other direction.

Answer (score 0):

Connect the SSD externally and install a clean os on it. Then run migration assistant to restore files to it from the internal drive (or from backup).

Once yours sure the SSD is viable and tested, then do the installation.

[This was the opposite](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54954/hard-disk-transfer-to-ssd-2007-macbook-and-lion) when drive swap was easy SATA and batteries were removable with a coin. Now you want to delay things that open the Mac until you’re sure your install is good.

Comment: how can I connect the SSD externally? the ssd is Aura Pro X2, I can't find an enclosure to put this drive in it and use it as external drive to clone my files

Comment: OWC sells kits that should work, @user263291 - https://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/S3DAPT4MB05K/

Comment: Also, good luck if this is your first repair / upgrade. OWC has amazing documentation, quality and support. Well worth the cost if you’re not super sure how to research and do DIY repairs.

Comment: that enclosure is only compatible with original mac ssd and now owc ssd.